# Comparing categorical variables between columns in pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, categories, categorical-data

**How do I make this comparison using the set categorical rules instead of the lexicon order rule?**

Given the dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NUMBER':[12, 26, 16, 34, 38, 1, 26, 8],
    'SHIRT_SIZE':['S', 'M', 'XL', 'L', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'],
    'SHIRT_SIZE2':['M', 'S', 'L', 'XL', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'S']
})
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
c_dtype = CategoricalDtype(categories = ["S","M","L","XL"],ordered = True)
df['SHIRT_SIZE'] = df['SHIRT_SIZE'].astype(c_dtype)
df['SHIRT_SIZE2'] = df['SHIRT_SIZE2'].astype(c_dtype)
```

|  | NUMBER | SHIRT_SIZE | SHIRT_SIZE2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 | S | M |
| 1 | 26 | M | S |
| 2 | 16 | XL | L |
| 3 | 34 | L | XL |
| 4 | 38 | S | M |
| 5 | 1 | M | L |
| 6 | 26 | L | XL |
| 7 | 8 | XL | S |

The `dtype` of `'SHIRT_SIZE'` and `'SHIRT_SIZE2'` is `Categories (4, object): ['S' < 'M' < 'L' < 'XL']`
I would like to compare the shirt sizes between the two columns `'SHIRT_SIZE'` and `'SHIRT_SIZE2'`

I attempted:

```
def compare_size(row):
    if (row['SHIRT_SIZE'] < row['SHIRT_SIZE2']):
        return 'SMALLER'
    elif (row['SHIRT_SIZE'] > row['SHIRT_SIZE2']):
        return 'LARGER'
    else:
        return 'SAME'

df['COMPARE_SIZE'] = df.apply(lambda row: compare_size(row), axis=1)
```

Resulting in:

|  | NUMBER | SHIRT_SIZE | SHIRT_SIZE2 | COMPARE_SIZE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 | S | M | LARGER |
| 1 | 26 | M | S | SMALLER |
| 2 | 16 | XL | L | LARGER |
| 3 | 34 | L | XL | SMALLER |
| 4 | 38 | S | M | LARGER |
| 5 | 1 | M | L | LARGER |
| 6 | 26 | L | XL | SMALLER |
| 7 | 8 | XL | S | LARGER |

**Notice that there are some rows *e.g. row 0 where 'S' -> 'M' and row 1 where 'M' -> 'S'* do not follow the order of our categorical `dtype` rules**

Logically, the interpretation is: "SHIRT_SIZE is <COMPARE_SIZE> THAN SHIRT_SIZE2"

I am guessing that the lexicon order of the string is the underlying rule used to compare these shirt sizes rather than the categorical rule we have set where `Categories (4, object): ['S' < 'M' < 'L' < 'XL']`.

I hope to compare the shirt sizes according to the categorical order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [numpy select](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi63umBk67uAhUjzDgGHZmUAAkQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnumpy.org%2Fdoc%2Fstable%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.select.html&usg=AOvVaw1Qy8n8VUClc_ZVC1Xf725k) to compare the values and genereate your new column:

```
condlist = [df.SHIRT_SIZE.gt(df.SHIRT_SIZE2), df.SHIRT_SIZE.lt(df.SHIRT_SIZE2)]
result_list = ["LARGER", "SMALLER"]
compare_size = np.select(condlist, result_list, "SAME")
df.assign(compare_size=compare_size)


    NUMBER  SHIRT_SIZE  SHIRT_SIZE2     compare_size
0   12  S   M   SMALLER
1   26  M   S   LARGER
2   16  XL  L   LARGER
3   34  L   XL  SMALLER
4   38  S   M   SMALLER
5   1   M   L   SMALLER
6   26  L   XL  SMALLER
7   8   XL  S   LARGER
```